# Saving SQLite database to a specific directory

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to make SQLite database from this example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example?msg=4949328#xx4949328xx)
Everything works fine, but what should I add to code, if I need to save my database to specific directory in SdCard? I need to know, where is my database in real device and work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your file will be stored in :

```
/datadata/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_name>
```

Comment: Problem is, I can't find /data/data/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_name> in file exproler. That is why I want to save my database to a differerent directory. I use device Huawei Ascend G6 and file manager show me only directories android/data/<my_app_package_name>, but my app isn't there. If I work with app I can see data in this app. For future using is better to have database in different directory.

Comment: I think you don't have to access the file while you can execute your queries on database. and I think you need root permission to see that file.

Comment: Do you mean root device?

Comment: thx. Hmmm, and if I save database to another directory, should I see it?

Comment: I think it's related to that directory. could you please accept my answer if it was helpful?